# How to 'snoop' a wired connection?

Tags: wired, network-monitoring

In the 'good old days' you could run 'snoop' on a wired network connection and see the packets going by. (Before the days of switches.)

I have a router that disconnected from anything other than my Ubuntu laptop. I have no idea what network it is set to use, and just broadcast pinging obvious possibilities gives me nothing.

The tools that exist seem to only work on WiFi interfaces not hardwired.

Ideas please.

David

Comment: This 'router' - it only works on Ethernet and not wifi anymore?  We need some details here to understand what exactly is happening and what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Ethernet snooping needs to be done with port mirrors at the switch/router levels, or with a Network TAP (Layer 1) device that enables traffic cloning/duplication across a link and 'mirrors' the traffic to a monitoring device port, which you can then listen on with Wireshark or similar to track the data.  (Basically, a plugged in and connected, but unconfigured, ethernet port).  TAPs are not cheap though, they run ~$150+ for gigabit network taps).  "Old days" used "Hubs" - the moment Routers and Switches came into play that 'old day' method needed some Layer1 tweaking to work with extra devices

Comment: Are you trying to snoop from the Ubuntu laptop, or do you intend to 'snoop' from a third device on the network?

Comment: I am wanting to snoop from the Ubuntu laptop. Just to see what the router may be sending out and from what IP address. The change to switches making snooping difficult is I suppose why I've lost contact with the method for 25 years or so.

Comment: tcpdump.  Or wireshark for a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

what I usually do when I find a lost device is connecting to it with my computer and setting tcpdump to listen to that wired interface:

ES: tcpdump -i eth0

in this way you might see some packets from the device and find it's ip.
I've used this workaround many times.

edit: in this case I'm using linux as my OS and have to launch the command with elevated privileges, thus with "sudo" infront or from the root user.

Comment: Not really sure this answers OP's question?

Comment: OP talks about snooping, but since they have the router hooked directly up to the pc I think that tcpdump reaches OP's goal (also since OP's is probing in attempts with pings the unknown network)

Comment: tcpdump is indeed what I needed. I'd just forgotten its existence. Haven't really had this problem since UTP networks. Used to use snoop on thin and yellow cable networks a lot.
I'm trying to set this router up as a secondary WiFi access point but I keep losing access to it.
Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: wireshark is a GUI application around tcpdump..  A lot easier to interpret the TCP or UDP traffic.